# Is there any continuous function having local minima at c but is neither decreasing in (c-h,c) nor increasing in (c,c+h)?

Tags: continuity

I can find a discontinuous function having the above conditions.....
f(x) =`x for x lying betwen (0,1) and (1,2)
and
-10 at x=1`
But can anyone help me in finding a continuous function satisfying the conditions....

Comment: What about $y=x^2\sin^2\frac{1}{x}$ for $x\ne 0$ and $y=0$ for $x=0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can consider the function
$$y=\bigg\{ \begin{array}{ccc} x^2 \sin^2\frac{1}{x}& &x\ne0
\\0 && x=0\end{array}$$
It is continuous and $(0,0)$ is a local minimum, but does not satisfy your conditions.

Comment: I still have a doubt...f(x) at 0.1 and - 0.1 are equal......i.e. it is decreasing in left interval and increasing in right.....

Comment: @user364168 the values at some arbitrarily chosen points $\pm 0,1$ are of no relevance in case of a highly oscillating map like the one proposed here.

Comment: Okay.....i understood....thank u all......